# RTEs accessibilityicons missing in TYPO3 7.6

Tags: icons, typo3, rte

After upgrading my project from TYPO3 4.x to TYPO3 7.6 there were many broken icons in the front-end:

```
<a href="mailto:mail@example.com" class="mail">
  <img src="typo3/sysext/rtehtmlarea/res/accessibilityicons/img/mail.gif" alt="">mail(at)example.com
</a>
```

The directory `typo3/sysext/rtehtmlarea/res/accessibilityicons/img/` is not there anymore.
How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the directory structure of the extension *rtehtmlarea* is aligned to the Extbase structure so that the location of some directories changed (Thx to Georg Ringer). The icons are located in `typo3/sysext/rtehtmlarea/Resources/Public/Images/` now.

You can easily change the whole content with this SQL snippet:

```
UPDATE tt_content 
  SET bodytext = REPLACE(bodytext, 
    'rtehtmlarea/res/accessibilityicons/img/', 
    'rtehtmlarea/Resources/Public/Images/');
```

This rewrites all occurrences of the icons to the new path.

Sometimes also this old path is used: `typo3/sysext/rtehtmlarea/htmlarea/plugins/TYPO3Browsers/img/mail.gif`
You can adjust obove SQL statement for this too.

Please backup your database before.

Comment: The extension is neither based on pibase nor on extbase but the structure of assets has been aligned with the rest of the core.